# Specifying value inside NSDictionary nested in a NSArray in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

How do I specify a value inside this array? All the values seem to be in a `NSDictionary` nested in the `NSArray`, which is only giving me one value inside the array. I've seen questions similar to this unfortunately all that i've found pertain to obj c and i've not been able to get anything to work in swift. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

**Code:**

```
    var url: NSString = "http://localhost:8888/dataQuery.php?"
    var data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: url as String)!)
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var result = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as! NSArray
    println(result[0])
```

Xcode Result:

```
 {
    seat1 = 1;
    seat2 = 0;
    seat3 = 0;
    seat4 = 0;
    seat5 = 1;
    seat6 = 0;
    seat7 = 0;
    seat8 = 0;
 }

 result NSArray "1 value"   0x78e86850
 [0]    __NSDictionaryM *   8 key/value pairs   0x78e867b0
 [0] = @"seat1" : @"1"  
 [1] = @"seat3" : @"0"  
 [2] = @"seat5" : @"1"  
 [3] = @"seat7" : @"0"  
 [4] = @"seat2" : @"0"  
 [5] = @"seat4" : @"0"  
 [6] = @"seat6" : @"0"  
 [7] = @"seat8" : @"0"
```

Comment: Can you just extract the dictionary from the array's 0th element?

Comment: Still learning, will do some more searching using that terminology.

Comment: Cast the value if you know the type: let dic = result[0] as! [String: String]

Comment: That worked, the help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!